# Bloquear o Control+V em campos TextBox gerados dinâmicamente

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Tenho uma `GridView` onde tenho varios `TextBox` que são gerados de acordo com o total de linhas dos mesmos.

Gostaria de bloquear o `Control+V` em todos os `TextBox`.

Uso o `Jquery 1.4`, e pelo que li o método `on` atualmente usado para os novos 
Jquerys corresponde ao `live` no `Jquery 1.4`.

Tentei o seguinte código mais não obtive sucesso e não da erro no log.

Sei que cada `TextBox` gerado também é gerado um `ID` diferente.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

> Meu Jquery

```
$("#<%=tbNaoAtende.ClientID%>").live('paste',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#<%=tbNaoAtendeInic.ClientID%>").live('paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#<%=tbAtendeRess.ClientID%>").live('paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#<%=tbAtende.ClientID%>").live('paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

> Meu aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="rptListaVerificacao" runat="server" PageSize="50" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="gridLV" AllowPaging="True" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Table ID="tbAtendimentos" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold; border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;"
            CellPadding="5">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, nao_atende%>"></asp:Literal>:</asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell Style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbNaoAtende" runat="server" Width="40px" CssClass="numero"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, nao_atende_iniciativa%>"></asp:Literal>:</asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell Style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbNaoAtendeInic" runat="server" Width="40px" CssClass="numero"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal9" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, atende_ressalva%>"></asp:Literal>:</asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell Style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbAtendeRess" runat="server" Width="40px" CssClass="numero"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal10" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, atende%>"></asp:Literal>:</asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell Style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbAtende" runat="server" Width="40px" CssClass="numero"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtAtualizaAtendimento" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource, atualiza_atendimento%>"
                        OnClick="lbtAtualizaAtendimento_Click"></asp:LinkButton></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui pegando por "class"
da seguinte forma.

```
  $(function () {
      $(".numero").live('paste', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma função javascript para fazer isso, por exemplo:

```
 function Verificar()
 {
  var ctrl=window.event.ctrlKey;
  var tecla=window.event.keyCode;
  if (ctrl && tecla==67) {alert("CTRL+C"); event.keyCode=0; event.returnValue=false;}
  if (ctrl && tecla==86) {alert("CTRL+V"); event.keyCode=0; event.returnValue=false;}
 }
```

Já que está utilizando JQuery pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Quando criar o textbox:

```
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txt = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
 txt.CssClass = "numero";
```

Use a função JQuery como citado.

Comment: Como chamar essa função em um elemento criado dinamicamente Raí? Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Raí vc está colando o mesmo código que coloquei acima.

Comment: Não havia percebido, fiz uma menção a seu código.